# How to create custom C# widgets?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

What is the best approach and/or tool? 
The trackBar in the MS Visual Studio 2008 Toolbox is inadequate.
It needs to be optimized for an 800x480 touch screen in extreme environmental conditions.
The button on the trackBar needs to be larger so it is easier for the user to move the control using a finger. Its possible with the existing widget, but difficult since the button is small. I am using C# in MS Visual Studio 2008, but don't know if it is WinForms or WPF (this is my 1st C# project). The target is an old windows-ce tablet. It would be great if step-by-step instructions on how to create a custom control already exist. An alternative would be a tool I could purchase.

Comment: Can you define "widget"?

Comment: As it stands, your question is incredibly vague. It might help if you specified what technologies you're using: WinForms, WPF, etc. Also, what are the "inadequacies" of the `TrackBar` control that you'd like to overcome? And finally, are you looking for step-by-step instructions on how to create a custom control, or do you already know that and are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: if you don't clarify your question pretty soon, it will begin to acquire close votes.

Comment: I need to make the button on the trackBar larger so it is easier for the user to move the control using a finger.
Its possible with the existing widget, but difficult since the button is small.
I am using C# in MS Visual Studio 2008, but don't know if it is WinForms or WPF (this is my 1st C# project).
The target is an old windows-ce tablet.
It would be great if step-by-step instructions on how to create a custom control already exist.
An alternative would be a tool I could purchase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple tutorials on creating custom controls:

**Using Winforms**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2004/12/06/275505.aspx
http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/10/13/winforms-user-controls-101.aspx

**Using WPF**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx
http://www.wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html

It might be a good idea to read up on the basics, then ask more specific questions that you have regarding the nuances of creating a custom control.